# Add class on default placeholder to thumbnail (Wordpress loop)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm updating the classes in my loop.php and I've managed to get it all done aside from the image class. As well as this, I'd like to include a default placeholder image that is displayed if no image is updated. Can someone help?

Here's my currently loop.php code:

```
<!-- article -->
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('h-entry'); ?>>

    <!-- post thumbnail -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="h-entry__image-link">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120));
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- /post thumbnail -->

    <!-- post title -->
    <h2 class="p-name">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <!-- /post title -->

    <!-- post details -->
    <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" class="dt-published"><?php the_time('jS F Y'); ?></time>
    <!-- /post details -->

    <?php html5wp_summary('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="arrow-link">Read the full article</a></p>

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

</article>
<!-- /article -->
```

I did need to amend my summary text class in my functions.php using the following:

```
function html5wp_summary($length_callback = '', $more_callback = '')
{
    global $post;
    if (function_exists($length_callback)) {
        add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
    }
    if (function_exists($more_callback)) {
        add_filter('excerpt_more', $more_callback);
    }
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    $output = '<p class="p-summary">' . $output . '</p>';
    echo $output;
}
```

Not sure if I need to do something similar for the image but I can't get it working.

Thanks in advance and I hope someone can help :)

Comment: Do you mean `the_post_thumbnail` by image?

Comment: You already have `class="h-entry__image-link"`, do you want to change that? Or add to it?

Comment: it was the class on the actually `img` tag rather than the link. However, I think I can do that by adding another array on the end like this: `the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120),array('class' => 'u-featured'));` - does that seem ok? It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an else condition here

```
<!-- post thumbnail -->
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="h-entry__image-link">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php else {?>
               <img src="path to default image" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
 </a>
    <!-- /post thumbnail -->
```

Comment: If this is going to be the accepted answer then the least you can do is rewrite the code to remove the duplicate commands

Comment: I updated the code. check it. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code! I get an "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)" error :/ Also, I figured I can add a class by using this `<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120),array('class' => 'u-featured'));` if that seems ok?

Comment: I missed one bracket, Updated check

Comment: Hmmm I'm still getting an error. Something to do with `<?php else {?>` I think. That's the line it says there's an issue on anyways.

Comment: I have replaced `:` with `{ ` and removed `endif;` please make sure you are using my exact code.

Comment: Thanks again for your replies! I'm copy/pasting it over the existing code but it's just not working. If I remover the else and it's closing tag at the end the page doesn't break but obviously both placeholder and post image are displayed. There's something about that else it doesn't like! I'm having a play around now to see what it is.

Comment: Maybe something to do with Wordpress but this _seems_ to work. Changed the opening else tag to `<?php else: ?>` and the closing tag to `<?php endif; ?>`. No idea why the others didn't work. I found a similar if/else statement on a post page and copied from there.

Comment: If this solution fixes your issue, then mark this answer as correct, it will help other community users.